# ResultReceiver.send throws nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, intentservice

I have searched for an answer but I couldn't find one. I am reverse geocoding latitude and latitude in IntentService then when I try to ResultReceiver.send it throws nullpointerexception. I debugged the arguments and they contain the address and the result code just like they are supposed to. I searched on any uninitialized objects but I couldn't fine one. Can anyone give me a clue on what's going on?

This is the method that reversegeocodes the lat and lon.

```
@Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        String errorMessage = "";

        // Get the location passed to this service through an extra.
        Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(
                Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA);

        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude(),
                    // In this sample, get just one addresse.
                    1);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            // Catch network or other I/O problems.
            errorMessage = getString(R.string.service_not_available);
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage, ioException);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
            // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values.
            errorMessage = getString(R.string.invalid_lat_lon);
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage + ". " +
                    "Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() +
                    ", Longitude = " +
                    location.getLongitude(), illegalArgumentException);
        }

        // Handle case where no address was found.
        if (addresses == null || addresses.size()  == 0) {
            if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
                errorMessage = getString(R.string.no_address_found);
                Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            }
            deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage);
        } else if (!"".equals(addresses) || null != addresses || addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            ArrayList<String> addressFragments = new ArrayList<String>();

            // Fetch the address lines using getAddressLine,
            // join them, and send them to the thread.
            for(int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
            }
            //Log.i(TAG, getString(R.string.no_address_found));
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(String.valueOf(addressFragments)))
            //this is the line number 95 mentioned in the logcat
            deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT, TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"), addressFragments));
        }
        //GetAddressString(addresses);
        //return st;
    }

private void deliverResultToReceiver(int resultCode, String message) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        try {
            if (message != null || !"".equals(message))
        bundle.putString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY, message);
               //this is line number 113 mentioned in the logcat
                mReceiver.send(resultCode, bundle);
            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                npe.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Here is the logcat

```
02-26 16:03:58.601: I/SELinux(7548): Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
02-26 16:03:58.601: I/SELinux(7548):  
02-26 16:03:58.601: I/SELinux(7548): Function: selinux_android_load_priority [1], There is no sepolicy version file.
02-26 16:03:58.601: I/SELinux(7548):  
02-26 16:03:58.601: I/SELinux(7548): Function: selinux_android_load_priority , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G800H_4.4.2_0018
02-26 16:03:58.601: I/SELinux(7548):  
02-26 16:03:58.601: I/SELinux(7548):  
02-26 16:03:58.601: I/SELinux(7548): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
02-26 16:03:58.601: E/SELinux(7548): [DEBUG] seapp_context_lookup: seinfoCategory = default
02-26 16:03:58.601: E/dalvikvm(7548): >>>>> Normal User
02-26 16:03:58.601: E/dalvikvm(7548): >>>>> com.mypackage [ userId:0 | appId:10201 ]
02-26 16:03:58.621: E/SELinux(7548): [DEBUG] seapp_context_lookup: seinfoCategory = default
02-26 16:03:58.621: D/dalvikvm(7548): Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-26 16:03:58.671: D/TimaKeyStoreProvider(7548): in addTimaSignatureService
02-26 16:03:58.681: D/TimaKeyStoreProvider(7548): Cannot add TimaSignature Service, License check Failed
02-26 16:03:58.681: D/ActivityThread(7548): Added TimaKesytore provider
02-26 16:03:58.751: W/ActivityThread(7548): Application com.mypackage can be debugged on port 8100...
02-26 16:03:58.941: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(7548): Parent view is not a TextView
02-26 16:03:59.001: I/x(7548): Making Creator dynamically
02-26 16:03:59.041: I/Google Maps Android API(7548): Google Play services client version: 6587000
02-26 16:03:59.051: I/Google Maps Android API(7548): Google Play services package version: 6776036
02-26 16:03:59.941: I/dalvikvm(7548): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.ew.c
02-26 16:03:59.941: W/dalvikvm(7548): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 441: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
02-26 16:03:59.941: D/dalvikvm(7548): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000f
02-26 16:03:59.981: W/ActivityThread(7548): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple 
applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
02-26 16:04:00.021: D/AbsListView(7548): Get MotionRecognitionManager
02-26 16:04:00.081: I/System.out(7548): Thread-618(HTTPLog):isShipBuild true
02-26 16:04:00.081: I/System.out(7548): Thread-618(HTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
02-26 16:04:00.221: I/Adreno-EGL(7548): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
02-26 16:04:00.221: I/Adreno-EGL(7548): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
02-26 16:04:00.221: I/Adreno-EGL(7548): Build Date: 03/21/14 Fri
02-26 16:04:00.221: I/Adreno-EGL(7548): Local Branch: AU200+patches_03212014
02-26 16:04:00.221: I/Adreno-EGL(7548): Remote Branch: 
02-26 16:04:00.221: I/Adreno-EGL(7548): Local Patches: 
02-26 16:04:00.221: I/Adreno-EGL(7548): Reconstruct Branch: 
02-26 16:04:00.251: I/HWUI(7548): EGLImpl-HWUI Protected EGL context created
02-26 16:04:00.261: D/OpenGLRenderer(7548): Enabling debug mode 0
02-26 16:04:01.301: D/dalvikvm(7548): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 17677K, 55% free 16268K/35592K, paused 55ms, total 55ms
02-26 16:04:03.161: D/dalvikvm(7548): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7882K, 54% free 16547K/35592K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
02-26 16:04:08.201: W/System.err(7548): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 16:04:08.201: W/System.err(7548):     at com.mypackage.FetchAddressIntentService.deliverResultToReceiver(FetchAddressIntentService.java:113)
02-26 16:04:08.201: W/System.err(7548):     at com.mypackage.FetchAddressIntentService.onHandleIntent(FetchAddressIntentService.java:95)
02-26 16:04:08.201: W/System.err(7548):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
02-26 16:04:08.201: W/System.err(7548):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-26 16:04:08.201: W/System.err(7548):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
02-26 16:04:08.211: W/System.err(7548):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Fixed it by instantiating the result resultreceiver object in the class that delivers the result to the main activity. MainActivity mac = new MainActivity();
     MainActivity.AddressResultReceiver mRReceiver = mac.new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler()); I know it is not good practice to instantiate an activity but for my own needs that was the only way that worked. Lesson learned, always instantiate an object before you use it in java :)

Answer (score 7):

The reason why you are getting a null pointer exception is because the ResultReceiver you have created has not been instantiated. The Google training on https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html doesn't seem to specifically deal with this but nonetheless, in the MainActivity of your app that request the "FetchAddressIntentService", you can instantiate the ResultReceiver.

MainActivity.java

```
protected void startIntentService() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddressIntentService.class);
    mResultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler()); //instantiate here
    intent.putExtra(RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);
    intent.putExtra(LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, mLastLocation);
    startService(intent);
}
```

Then in your FetchAddressIntentService.java, you will extract the mResultReceiver item out of the intent bundle like this:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle parameters = intent.getExtras();
    mReceiver = parameters.getParcelable(RECEIVER); }
```

Rerun your code and the null pointer exception disappears as we have instantiated.

Comment: This is the solution to the issue. It should be marked as the correct answer

Comment: Just billiant! the android documentation example does not include this part . Tx